# Unable to print in Arabic on Xprinter XP-P810 using Android Studio

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, arabic

I am trying to print an string containing Arabic characters, but when I print it, the paper is blank.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    try {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}, InvoiceActivity_AR.PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH);

        } else {

            BluetoothConnection connection = BluetoothPrintersConnections.selectFirstPaired();

            if (connection != null) {

                EscPosPrinter printer = new EscPosPrinter(connection, 203, 78f, 48);

                final String text = "[C]شركة الحياة";

                printer.printFormattedText(text);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No printer was connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("APP", "Can't print", e);
    }
```

At first I thought that this printer does not support Arabic. But I tried to print from text app and it worked normally.

I am using this plugin:
https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

Please help me fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be covered by [this](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/issues/198) and possibly [this](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android#charset-encoding).

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried changing the code page but with no luck